# Python failing to import my modules

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project, and am attempting to set up the URLConf for an app I have created in it. (You don't really need to understand Django to understand my issue)

Here are the relevant parts of my project

```
 /PROJECT
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
/home
    __init__.py
    views.py
/user
    __init__.py
    views.py
```

I am attempting to import `home` from `PROJECT/urls.py`:

```
PROJECT/urls.py (relevant parts)

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
import user
import home  # <---

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home.views.index, name='index'),  # <---
    url(r'^register/$', user.views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', user.views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', user.views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

For some reason importing `user` *does* work, while importing `home` (and its submodules) *does not*.

When I run Django's built in web server I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'home' has no attribute 'views'
```

I *do not* get this error for importing `user` and its submodules

I should note that when I run `urls.py` in a normal python shell it comes back with import errors for both `home` and `user`, though only `home` errors when I run Django's webserver. The `user` part of my code has been running fine since the beginning, and I assume it errors in a normal shell as it is not supposed to be run by itself.

Again, for some reason I cannot fathom, `user` imports correctly, while `home` does not, despite being no apparent differences between them.

This is in Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9

Comment: Which python version? In Python2 there is a `user` module that you may be getting instead of your intended one.

Comment: Python 3.5, sorry, should have said

Comment: Judging from the error, a `home` module *is* imported, but probably not the one you wanted. Use `print home` to check where the `home` got loaded from.

Comment: have you added home in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: @navyad, yes I have.

Comment: @user4815162342, I did that, it is definitely importing the correct module (but not its sub modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
import home.views
```

When you import a package in Python, it does not recursively import all of its subpackages or modules contained in it.

The reason why `import user` works is not obvious, but it might be because you are importing views inside `user/__init__.py`. Barring that, it's also possible that another module imports `user.views` before it is being accessed in the `url` call. That makes Python insert the `views` module into the namespace of the `user` package after the fact.

Consider the following example:

```
/tmp/importtest $  mkdir mod_a mod_b
/tmp/importtest $  touch mod_{a,b}/__init__.py
/tmp/importtest $  echo 'A=1' > mod_a/a.py
/tmp/importtest $  echo 'B=2' > mod_b/b.py
/tmp/importtest $  echo 'import mod_b.b' > mod_c.py
/tmp/importtest $  python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jan  4 2016, 22:02:53) 
[GCC 4.9.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mod_a, mod_b
>>> mod_a.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> mod_b.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'
>>> import mod_c
>>> mod_b.b
<module 'mod_b.b' from '/tmp/importtest/mod_b/b.py'>
>>> mod_a.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
>>>
```

As you can see, before importing `mod_c`, there was nothing inside `mod_b`, but that changed once `mod_c` was imported, because it had a side-effect of inserting the `b` object into the namespace of `mod_b`.

Does this make it any clearer?

In conclusion, if you want to access `user.views` or `home.views`, always import `user.views` and `home.views` instead of just importing the top-level package and hoping that something else just happens to have the right side effect.

Comment: Thank you, this does work.
But why would user be working correctly? user/__init__.py is empty

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The answer is relevant, correct, clear, and it resolves the OP's problem. It is not obvious to someone new to Python that importing a package will not automatically import any of its submodules.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I don't believe user.views is being imported by anything else, but I'll do that research in my own time. Thanks again

Comment: You can always raise an exception at module level in `user.views`, just to get a traceback dumped into stderr (or use `traceback.print_stack`); that should reveal which import statement exactly is responsible for loading that module.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to add `home` folder to your python environment.

```
# in your Django settings
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

# add here
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "home"))

# now you can use home
from home import view
```

Also relative imports in python2 and python3 works different.